# 'Unable to get the Sumif property of the worksheetfunction Class' within visual basic

Tags: excel, vba

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZymI.jpg)

Can anyone explain how I am able to fix this?

After searching around I tried adding `Range` inside the brackets but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. Here is the current code:

```
 Sub ValidationNo5()

'Advise number of manual loads of 25t (loader buckets), 138t (standard truck loads) and other in data.

Dim Marra As Range
Dim MarraTonnes As Range
Dim MarraShiftDay As Range
Dim MarraShift As Range
Dim MarraLat As Range
Dim MarraLong As Range
Dim Saddle As Range
Dim SaddleTonnes As Range
Dim SaddleShiftDay As Range
Dim SaddleShift As Range
Dim SaddleLat As Range
Dim SaddleLong As Range
Dim ROMsTonnes As Range
Dim ROMsShiftDay As Range
Dim ROMsShift As Range
Dim ROMsLat As Range
Dim ROMsLong As Range
Dim CurrentDay As Date
Dim CurrentShift As String
Dim FinishDay As Date
Dim FinishShift As String

Set Marra = M_Hoppers.Range("A2")
Set Saddle = S_Hoppers.Range("A2")
Set ROMCell = ROMs.Range("A2")

If Marra <> "" Then
    Set MarraShiftDay = Range(M_Hoppers.Range("B2"), M_Hoppers.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set MarraShift = Range(M_Hoppers.Range("C2"), M_Hoppers.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set MarraTonnes = Range(M_Hoppers.Range("H2"), M_Hoppers.Range("H1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set MarraLat = Range(M_Hoppers.Range("I2"), M_Hoppers.Range("I1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set MarraLong = Range(M_Hoppers.Range("J2"), M_Hoppers.Range("J1048576").End(xlUp))
End If

If Saddle <> "" Then
    Set SaddleShiftDay = Range(S_Hoppers.Range("B2"), S_Hoppers.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set SaddleShift = Range(S_Hoppers.Range("C2"), S_Hoppers.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set SaddleTonnes = Range(S_Hoppers.Range("H2"), S_Hoppers.Range("H1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set SaddleLat = Range(S_Hoppers.Range("I2"), S_Hoppers.Range("I1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set SaddleLong = Range(S_Hoppers.Range("J2"), S_Hoppers.Range("J1048576").End(xlUp))
End If

If ROMCell <> "" Then
    Set ROMsShiftDay = Range(ROMs.Range("B2"), ROMs.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set ROMsShift = Range(ROMs.Range("C2"), ROMs.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set ROMsTonnes = Range(ROMs.Range("H2"), ROMs.Range("H1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set ROMsLat = Range(ROMs.Range("I2"), ROMs.Range("I1048576").End(xlUp))
    Set ROMsLong = Range(ROMs.Range("J2"), ROMs.Range("J1048576").End(xlUp))
End If

ValidationHeader = 5
ValidationFooter = 5

If StartShift = "DS" And EndShift = "NS" Then
    NoShifts = (DateDiff("d", datFirstDay, datLastDay) + 1) * 2
ElseIf (StartShift = "DS" And EndShift = "DS") Or (StartShift = "NS" And EndShift = "NS") Then
    NoShifts = (DateDiff("d", datFirstDay, datLastDay) + 0.5) * 2
ElseIf StartShift = "NS" And EndShift = "DS" Then
    NoShifts = DateDiff("d", datFirstDay, datLastDay) * 2
End If

If StartShift = "DS" Then
    CurrentShift = "DS"
    CurrentDay = datFirstDay
Else
    CurrentShift = "NS"
    CurrentDay = datFirstDay
End If

If EndShift = "DS" Then
    FinishShift = "NS"
    FinishDay = datLastDay
Else
    FinishShift = "DS"
    FinishDay = datLastDay + 1
End If

Val5Err = 0

If NoShifts > 0 Then

    Do
    
        PctDone = (1 + Val1Task + Val2Task + Val3Task + Val4Task + (PercentComp / Val5Task)) / (Val1Task + Val2Task + Val3Task + Val4Task + Val5Task + 1)
        With UserForm3
            .FrameProgress.Caption = Format(PctDone, "0%")
            .LabelProgress.Width = PctDone * (.FrameProgress.Width - 10)
            .Label2.Caption = "Validating data... Performing Validation 4"
        End With
        DoEvents
    
        If Marra <> "" And Saddle <> "" And ROMCell <> "" Then
        
            If (WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "") + _
                WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "") + _
                WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "")) > 0 Then
            
                If Val5Err = 0 Then
                    Call Validation_Header
                End If
                
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 0) = CurrentDay
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 1) = CurrentShift
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) = WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 25) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 25) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) = WF.CountIfs(MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 25) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 25) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) = WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 138) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 138) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) = WF.CountIfs(MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 138) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 138) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10) = WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, "<>" & 25, MarraTonnes, "<>" & 138) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 25, SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 138) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 25, ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) = WF.CountIfs(MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, "<>" & 25, MarraTonnes, "<>" & 138) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 25, SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 138) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 25, ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 12) = VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) & " loads, totalling " & _
                                            Round(VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10), 0) & "t were entered manually for " & CurrentShift & " on " & CurrentDay
                Val5Err = Val5Err + 1
                
            End If
            
        ElseIf Marra <> "" And Saddle <> "" And ROMCell = "" Then
                    
            If (WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "") + _
                WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "")) > 0 Then
            
                If Val5Err = 0 Then
                    Call Validation_Header
                End If
                
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 0) = CurrentDay
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 1) = CurrentShift
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) = WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 25) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) = WF.CountIfs(MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 25) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) = WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 138) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) = WF.CountIfs(MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 138) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10) = WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, "<>" & 25, MarraTonnes, "<>" & 138) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 25, SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) = WF.CountIfs(MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, "<>" & 25, MarraTonnes, "<>" & 138) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 25, SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 12) = VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) & " loads, totalling " & _
                                            Round(VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10), 0) & "t were entered manually for " & CurrentShift & " on " & CurrentDay
                Val5Err = Val5Err + 1
                
            End If
            
        ElseIf Marra <> "" And Saddle = "" And ROMCell = "" Then
                    
            If (WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "")) > 0 Then
                
                If Val5Err = 0 Then
                    Call Validation_Header
                End If
                
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 0) = CurrentDay
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 1) = CurrentShift
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) = WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) = WF.CountIfs(MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) = WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) = WF.CountIfs(MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10) = WF.SumIfs(MarraTonnes, MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, "<>" & 25, MarraTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) = WF.CountIfs(MarraShiftDay, CurrentDay, MarraShift, CurrentShift, MarraLat, "", MarraLong, "", MarraTonnes, "<>" & 25, MarraTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 12) = VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) & " loads, totalling " & _
                                            Round(VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10), 0) & "t were entered manually for " & CurrentShift & " on " & CurrentDay
                Val5Err = Val5Err + 1
                
            End If
            
        ElseIf Marra = "" And Saddle <> "" And ROMCell <> "" Then
                
            If (WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "") + _
                WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "")) > 0 Then
                
                If Val5Err = 0 Then
                    Call Validation_Header
                End If
                
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 0) = CurrentDay
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 1) = CurrentShift
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) = WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 25) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) = WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 25) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) = WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 138) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) = WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 138) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10) = WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 25, SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 138) + _
                                        WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 25, ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) = WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 25, SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 138) + _
                                        WF.CountIfs(ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 25, ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 12) = VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) & " loads, totalling " & _
                                            Round(VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10), 0) & "t were entered manually for " & CurrentShift & " on " & CurrentDay
                Val5Err = Val5Err + 1
                
            End If
            
        ElseIf Marra = "" And Saddle <> "" And ROMCell = "" Then
            
            If (WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "")) > 0 Then
                
                If Val5Err = 0 Then
                    Call Validation_Header
                End If
                
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 0) = CurrentDay
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 1) = CurrentShift
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) = WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) = WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) = WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) = WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10) = WF.SumIfs(SaddleTonnes, SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 25, SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) = WF.CountIfs(SaddleShiftDay, CurrentDay, SaddleShift, CurrentShift, SaddleLat, "", SaddleLong, "", SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 25, SaddleTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 12) = VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) & " loads, totalling " & _
                                            Round(VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10), 0) & "t were entered manually for " & CurrentShift & " on " & CurrentDay
                Val5Err = Val5Err + 1
                
            End If
            
        ElseIf Marra = "" And Saddle = "" And ROMCell <> "" Then
                
            If (WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "")) > 0 Then
                
                If Val5Err = 0 Then
                    Call Validation_Header
                End If
                
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 0) = CurrentDay
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 1) = CurrentShift
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) = WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) = WF.CountIfs(ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 25)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) = WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) = WF.CountIfs(ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10) = WF.SumIfs(ROMsTonnes, ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 25, ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) = WF.CountIfs(ROMsShiftDay, CurrentDay, ROMsShift, CurrentShift, ROMsLat, "", ROMsLong, "", ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 25, ROMsTonnes, "<>" & 138)
                VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 12) = VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 5) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 8) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 11) & " loads, totalling " & _
                                            Round(VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 3) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 6) + VECell.Offset(Val5Err, 10), 0) & "t were entered manually for " & CurrentShift & " on " & CurrentDay
                Val5Err = Val5Err + 1
                
            End If
            
        End If
        
        If CurrentShift = "DS" Then
            CurrentShift = "NS"
        Else
            CurrentShift = "DS"
            CurrentDay = CurrentDay + 1
        End If
        
    Loop Until CurrentShift = FinishShift And CurrentDay = FinishDay

End If

If Val5Err > 0 Then
    Call Validation_Footer
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image- you can copy and paste as text into your question.  We have no idea what those arguments you're passing to `SumIfs`, so it would help to add that information also.

Comment: I am sorry about that, I am very new to scripting and this site as well. I have added the full sub-process code now.

Comment: Just curious, In your code I don't see that you declare/set the WF variable ? I don't see something like `Dim WF As WorksheetFunction: Set WF = Application.WorksheetFunction`. Please CMIIW.

Comment: The way you declare your ranges there's no guarantee they'll all be the same size - are they?

Comment: @Tim Williams Can you please elaborate on that with an example please?

Comment: `M_Hoppers.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp)` may not be the same row as `S_Hoppers.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp)`, if your rows aren't fully populated.  You sohlud set the end for for all the ranges to be the same, based on some column you know always has a value.

Comment: ...the ranges you pass into `SumIfs` need to all be the same size....

Comment: The criteria ranges in the Sumifs need to be the same size but the criteria won't be?

Comment: @karma that is correct

Comment: @TimWilliams ??

Comment: Yes the criteria ranges need to be the same size.  You’ll see the same issue if you try out the formula with unequal ranges on a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

When using `SumIfs()` your criteria ranges should all be the same size.

For example:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim WF As WorksheetFunction, rngA As Range, rngB As Range, rngC As Range
    
    Set WF = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    Set rngA = Range("A1:A5") 'all ranges same size
    Set rngB = Range("B1:B5")
    Set rngC = Range("C1:C5")
    
    Debug.Print WF.SumIfs(rngA, rngB, "T", rngC, "X") 'OK: 6
    
    Set rngB = Range("B1:B4")  'not same size...
    Debug.Print WF.SumIfs(rngA, rngB, "T", rngC, "X") 'Error
        
End Sub
```

If you do this:

```vb
Set MarraShiftDay = Range(M_Hoppers.Range("B2"), M_Hoppers.Range("B1048576").End(xlUp))
Set MarraShift = Range(M_Hoppers.Range("C2"), M_Hoppers.Range("C1048576").End(xlUp))
Set MarraTonnes = Range(M_Hoppers.Range("H2"), M_Hoppers.Range("H1048576").End(xlUp))
Set MarraLat = Range(M_Hoppers.Range("I2"), M_Hoppers.Range("I1048576").End(xlUp))
Set MarraLong = Range(M_Hoppers.Range("J2"), M_Hoppers.Range("J1048576").End(xlUp))
```

there's no guarantee that those 5 `End(xlUp)` all arive at the exact same "last row"